# I can not see the background of Linearlayout

Tags: android, background, android-linearlayout

Good morning!

I have a question about Linearlayout.
I set the background color in XML and the background is changing when I run the app.

But if i put the code in the button listener on the app and change it, there is no change
For what reason?

**LinearLayout XML code

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/page"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@color/white"
>
```

**MyActivity Code

```
page = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.page);
page.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray2));
page.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yellow);
```

Comment: i'm solution. not exploblem of code.
just my fault.

Answer (score 0):

It is working when i tried to recreate scnerio . Can you show the listner code which you added for background